# Custom validator with spring boot for list of files

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, spring-validator

I am trying to write a custom validator to validate a list of files.

Controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyController {

@PostMapping(value = "/getDetails", consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<String> getDetails(@Valid @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] extractionRequest){
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Success", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

FilePart.java

```
@Data
public class FilePart {
    @FilePartConstraint
    private List<MultipartFile> files;
}
```

FilePartConstraint.java

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = FilePartRequestValidator.class)
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface FilePartConstraint {
    String message() default "Error while validation of Images";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

FilePartRequestValidator.java

```
public class FilePartRequestValidator implements ConstraintValidator<FilePartConstraint, List<MultipartFile>> {


private String constraintMessage;
    private String fileName;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\.(?:jpg|gif|png|jpeg|JPG|GIF|PNG|JPEG)");
    
    @Override
    public void initialize(FilePartConstraint files) {
        System.out.println("inside initialize");
        constraintMessage = files.message();
        System.out.println("constraintMessage ::::: " + constraintMessage);
        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(List<MultipartFile> files, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        System.out.println("Files: " + files); 
        return true;
    }
}
```

Issue:
I am not able to use my validator

Any Suggestions

Comment: You have hardcoded isValid as false, what do you expect to happen? Please edit your question to provide more context. What do you want to validate and why it's not working

Comment: Thank you @KrzysztofK , I have updated the code, and added my concern

Comment: Did you debug endpoint to check if files are populated there?

Comment: @KrzysztofK Thanks for your help, I was not able to get the file, now I changed my Controller, but am not able to apply the annotation